# Does not evaluate the Integral and a plane plot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to compute a ContourPlot and a VectorPlot using the following functions:

```
k = 2 π/(632.8*10^(-9)) 
α = ArcSin[0.95]

a = Exp[-(Tan[θ]^2/Tan[α]^2)] BesselJ[1, Tan[θ]/ Tan[α]]
```

a is to apply into the functions ex and ey. These are the electric field components.

```
ex = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
NIntegrate[
 NIntegrate[
  a Sqrt[Cos[θ]]
    Sin[θ] Exp[
    I k ( x Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ] + 
       y Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ] + 
       z Cos[θ])] (-Sin[ϕ]), {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 20], {θ, 
  0, α}, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20] Assumptions -> {y > 0}]


ey = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
NIntegrate[
 NIntegrate[
  a Sqrt[Cos[θ]]
    Sin[θ] Exp[
    I k ( x Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ] + 
       y Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ] + 
       z Cos[θ])] (Cos[ϕ]), {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 20], {θ, 
  0, α}, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20] Assumptions :> Element[x, Reals]]
```

If I try to set values into the function it only gives me back the function itself.Then I tried to evaluate the integrals with `Assumptions`. It does not work and I don't know how to apply this to 2 variables.

```
{ex, ey} /. {x -> 2, y -> 1}
```

Plotting ex and ey with ContourPlot does not give me anything either. (if it is done right, there are round contours.)

I used bbgodfreys suggestions and plotted a ContourPlot. The Outcome wasn't expected.

```
ContourPlot[
Re[ex[r, -10, 10] + Re[ey[r, -10, 10]]], {r, 0, 10}, {\[Phi]0, 0, 
10}]
```

and got:

[image]

Comment: 1) As far as I know, `NIntegrate` does not take `Assumptions` options. 2) you have syntax errors in the positioning of your `Assumptions statements` as well. 3) There is a lot going on in your code: have you tried constructing a much simpler example and getting that to work first?

Comment: Your usage of `Compile` is wrong. Work thorough some of the examples in the docs to see how it works.  (usage will be like `ex[1,2]` not `ex/. x->...` ).  There is of course no point to specifying `Assumptions` on `x,y` since they always will have distinct values inside the function.

Comment: I tried it first without Assumptions and without the a. But it was the same. I tried it without `Compile`, too.

Comment: on further thought I don't see any point to using `Compile` here in the first place.

Comment: I tried `ey[0, 0]` but it took so long so I canceled it.  Plus it says: `NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be simplified enormously by performing the integral over `ϕ` symbolically.  To do so, first consider the `ϕ`-dependent exponential in the integrand.

```
Exp[I k (x Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ] + y Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ] + z Cos[θ])]
```

It can be transformed and simplified as follows.

```
expt = Exp[I k ( x Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ] + y Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ] + z Cos[θ])] /. 
       {x -> r Cos[ϕ0], y -> r Sin[ϕ0]} // Simplify
(* E^(I k (z Cos[θ] + r Cos[ϕ - ϕ0] Sin[θ])) *)
```

Now, perform the `ϕ` integrals

```
exϕ = Integrate[expt (-Sin[ϕ]), {ϕ, 0, 2 π}][[1]]
(* -2 I E^(I k z Cos[θ]) π BesselJ[1, k r Sin[θ]] Sin[ϕ0] *)

eyϕ = Integrate[expt Cos[ϕ], {ϕ, 0, 2 π}][[1]]
(* 2 I E^(I k z Cos[θ]) π BesselJ[1, k r Sin[θ]] Cos[ϕ0] *)
```

These results next are copied into the `θ` integrals

```
ex[r_, ϕ0_, z_] := NIntegrate[a Sqrt[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] 
     (-2 I E^(I k z Cos[θ]) π BesselJ[1, k r Sin[θ]] Sin[ϕ0]), {θ,  0, α}]
ey[r_, ϕ0_, z_] := NIntegrate[a Sqrt[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] 
     (2 I E^(I k z Cos[θ]) π BesselJ[1, k r Sin[θ]] Cos[ϕ0]), {θ,  0, α}]
```

A sample result is

```
Plot[Im[ey[r, π/4, 0]], {r, 0, 20/k}, AxesLabel -> {r, "Im[ey]"}]
```

[image]

**Edit: Contour Plot**

`ContourPlot`s of the functions `ex` and `ey` can be generated in a straightforward manner, although the process is a bit slow.  To modestly improve speed and simplify coding, rescale `r` and `z` by `k`, and factor `-2 π I Sin[ϕ0]` from `ex` and `2 π I Cos[ϕ0]` from `ey` to obtain

```
e[r_, z_] := NIntegrate[a Sqrt[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] Exp[I z Cos[θ]] BesselJ[1, r Sin[θ]],
   {θ,  0, α}, PrecisionGoal -> ∞, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

Note that `AccuracyGoal` is reduced as well.  I have not experimented with `Method`, which may further improve speed.  Finally, if only `Re[e]` is desired, use

```
eRe[r_, z_] := NIntegrate[a Sqrt[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] Cos[z Cos[θ]] BesselJ[1, r Sin[θ]],
     {θ,  0, α}, PrecisionGoal -> ∞, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
ContourPlot[eRe[r, z], {r, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"k r", "k z"}, ContourLabels -> True]
```

[image]

The imaginary part can be obtained by replacing `Cos[z Cos[θ]]` by `Sin[z Cos[θ]]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works much more quicker now. What do I do if I want to do a ContourPlot with ex+ey? I can not plot it over  x and y axis anymore right? But over  the r and ϕ0?

Comment: @donut  Please see material added to answer.  I hope that this is helpful.

Comment: this helps! One last question, now I want to put ex and ey into my s0,1,2,3. I have to transform the e back right?

Comment: `s0 = ex  Conjugate[ex] + ey Conjugate[ey];
s1 = ex Conjugate[ex] - ey Conjugate[ey];
s2 = ex Conjugate[ey] + ey Conjugate[ex];
s3 = I (ex Conjugate[ey] + ey Conjugate[ex]);`  like this? `VectorPlot[{s1[r, z], s2[r, z]}, {r, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]`

Comment: @donut  Yes, although it is easier to work with `-2 π I Sin[ϕ0] e[r, z]` and  `2 π I Cos[ϕ0] e[r, z]` instead of `ex[r, ϕ0, z]`  and `ey[r, ϕ0, z]`.  Also, I would use `{r, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}`. because `r` has a minimum value of zero, and the `s` are symmetric or antisymmetric about `z = 0`.  If my answer meets your need, please do not forget to accept it.  Best wishes.

Comment: hm I rewrote the functions to: `s1[r_, z_] = -2 π I Sin[ϕ0] e[r, 
     z] Conjugate[-2 π I Sin[ϕ0] e[r, z]] - 
   2 π I Cos[ϕ0] e[r, z] Conjugate[
     2 \[Pi] I Cos[ϕ0] e[r, z]];
s2[r_, z_] = -2 π I Sin[ϕ0] e[r, z] Conjugate[
     2 \[Pi] I Cos[ϕ0] e[r, z]] + 
   2 \[Pi] I Cos[ϕ0] e[r, 
     z]  Conjugate[-2 π I Sin[ϕ0] e[r, z]];
s3[r_, z_] = 
  I (-2 π I Sin[ϕ0] e[r, z]  Conjugate[
       2 π I Cos[ϕ0] e[r, z]] + 
     2 π I Cos[ϕ0] e[r, 
       z]  Conjugate[-2 π I Sin[ϕ0] e[r, z]]);`

Comment: and then used `VectorPlot[{s1[r, z], s2[r, z]}, {r, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}]` but still got a plain plot. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @donut  Expanding your `s1` and `s2` expressions yields `-(2 π Abs[e[r, z]])^2 Cos[2 ϕ0]` and `-(2 π Abs[e[r, z]])^2 Sin[2 ϕ0]`, respectively.  In order to plot these quantities, it is necessary first to specify `ϕ0`.

Comment: sorry but I'm stuck. Do you mean to define ϕ0 like this:`ϕ0 -> ArcTan[x, y]` and `r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]`

Comment: @donut  Just give it a value, like π/8.  Note, though, that `s1` and `s2` are proportional, so the VectorPlot is not likely to be very interesting.